# if df.A=0 & df.b=1 then df.c=1/ pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df:

```
A  B
0  1
1  1
0  0
```

**Aim**: if df.A=0 & df.B=1 then create a column C=1 else return nothing. The result should be:
df:

```
A  B  C
0  1  1
1  1
0  0
0  1  1
```

My current code gives this error: "ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if df.A==0 and df.B==1 else '', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
m=(df['A'].eq(0)) & (df['B'].eq(1))
#Finally:
df['C'] =m.astype(int).replace(0,'')
```

OR

```
#import numpy as np
m=(df['A'].eq(0)) & (df['B'].eq(1))
df['C']=np.where(m,1,'')
```

OR

For your current method use bitwise `&` and `x[column name]`:

```
df['C']=df.apply(lambda x: 1 if (x['A']==0) & (x['B']==1) else '', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XOR operator `^` and `replace`

```
df["C"] = (df.A ^ df.B).replace(0, '')
df
   A  B  C
0  0  1  1
1  1  1
2  0  0
3  0  1  1
```